# Displaying matplotlib plot using Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, flask

I want to visualize the plot (SciView) in my Flask web project.

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
# x-coordinates of left sides of bars 
left = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
# heights of bars 
height = [10, 24, 36, 40, 5] 
# labels for bars 
tick_label = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'] 
# plotting a bar chart 
plt.bar(left, height, tick_label=tick_label, width=0.8, color=['red', 'green']) 
# naming the y-axis 
plt.xlabel('y - axis') 
# naming the x-axis 
plt.xlabel('x - axis') 
# plot title 
plt.title('My bar chart!') 
# function to show the plot 
plt.show()
```

I've tried running this code in my Flask project, but there is no output.

Comment: "this is my code" - where is it?

Comment: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# x-coordinates of left sides of bars
left = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

# heights of bars
height = [10, 24, 36, 40, 5]

# labels for bars
tick_label = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']

# plotting a bar chart
plt.bar(left, height, tick_label=tick_label,
        width=0.8, color=['red', 'green'])

# naming the x-axis
plt.xlabel('x - axis')
# naming the y-axis
plt.ylabel('y - axis')
# plot title
plt.title('My bar chart!')

# function to show the plot
plt.show()

Comment: Please include your code _in your post_ and `format it`.

Comment: Typically, you'd use something like Plotly or D3.js in Flask. Matplotlib is meant primarly for desktop use-cases.

Comment: I would also suggest that almost all of those comments are unnecessary. They clutter up the code and make it harder to read, as well as providing no new information that isn't already contained in the code itself.

Answer (score 6):

A possible solution is to save the figure with `plt.savefig` and attach it to an HTML `<img>` tag.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/plot')
def plot():
    left = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    # heights of bars
    height = [10, 24, 36, 40, 5]
    # labels for bars
    tick_label = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
    # plotting a bar chart
    plt.bar(left, height, tick_label=tick_label, width=0.8, color=['red', 'green'])

    # naming the y-axis
    plt.ylabel('y - axis')
    # naming the x-axis
    plt.xlabel('x - axis')
    # plot title
    plt.title('My bar chart!')

    plt.savefig('static/images/plot.png')

    return render_template('plot.html', url='/static/images/plot.png')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

Then on templates/plot.html

```
<img src={{url}} alt="Chart" height="auto" width="100%">
```

Comment: How to recreate this simple application around MVC pattern? 
Does Flask support MVC pattern?